# Infinite Perfect power of numbers in a certain form

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, exponentiation, perfect-powers

A question I found very interesting , which I found written on a blackboard while visiting a near by community science center is as follows.

> Prove that there exist infinitely many $m,n,k$ for which $1^k+2^k+3^k \cdots +n^k$ is a perfect $m$ power.

I have been trying this from many days but I am unable to make out how to do it . I got one thing that $1^k+2^k+3^k \cdots +n^k | \; n+1$ but I don't thing this would help.

Comment: Apart from trivial cases, and $k=1$, $m=2$ (Pell equation) there seems nothing obvious.

Comment: Note that $1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3$ is always a square.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions with $m=2$ -- as André noted, the case with $k=1$ gives you infinitely many solutions via Pell's equation. I can't find any solutions where $m$ is not a power of 2 (excepting the trivial cases $n\in\{0,1\}$).